# How to store sensitive data in Android using ADOBE AIR

Tags: android, air, adobe

I built an android application using Adobe AIR and I am storing some data in XML, where each created XML file belongs to a single user. I need to save in a table the connection between (userID and filename) so that when a user Logs In it would access the file with the corresponding filename. That table must be secure and only the app must have access to it. Ive heard about "Shared Preferences" in Android but I can't seem to find any info in Google how to manipulate it using Adobe AIR. Do you know any way I can access "Shared Preferences" or is there any other option I have to store sensitive data?

P.S. Ive seen "Encrypted local storage" but it doesnt give protection when the user has root access.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what is is worth, the number of rooted phones are fairly low. Unless you are specifically targeting that market (which you would unlikely use AIR to do), it is likely too low to worry about `EncryptedLocalStorage`. I have no data to back it up, but I remember last summer reading it was less than 2% of all Android devices. If you really want to use a native feature that isn't in AIR, you'll have to build an AIR Native Extension (ANE) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

EncryptedLocalStorage isn't easily viewable even on rooted mobiles, but anyway use encrypted SQLite instead, it's more easier to deal with it instead of using many XML files.

Look here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/encrypted_database.html

And here also:
http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/62